# Custom Tabbed Page Renderer Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, custom-renderer, tabbed-view

So know how to set up a custom renderer (only partially apparently) with an OnElementChanged method. I followed this (http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17654/tabbedpage-icons-not-visible-android)

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        _activity = this.Context as Activity;
    }
```

This gets hit, but it never displays the page afterwards.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing up now. I had to use the base class of TabbedRender rather than TabbedPageRenderer. I also had to add this.SetWillNotDraw(false) in the CustomRenderer constructor.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to solve the problem? The derived class? Thank you.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/219263/#Comment_219263 have a look on this page... The second post of Mubi did it for me ;-)

Comment: Do you have a full code example of what worked for you? I tried this.setwillnotdraw and am using TabbedRenderer, and I have the same problem where it gets hit but then my page is just blank white. it never loads. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/TabbedPageRenderer.cs) you can find a full TabbedPageRenderer ready to be modified. It comes directly from Xamarin.Forms Android.
Still I'm trying to set a different *Font Size*...